# What is the correct term for an increasing or decreasing function which "flattens out"?

Tags: terminology

I'd like to say logarithmically decreasing but it does not have to decrease to zero.

An example of an increasing function which flattens out at around 4.5%.

[image]

Comment: It still isn't clear what "flatten out" means precisely.  Do $y=\sqrt{x}$ or $y=\log(x)$ "flatten out"?  These functions have the property that they are always increasing, do not tend to a finite limit, but their *rate of increase* goes to $0$ as $x$ goes to infinity.

Comment: @Jonas: No, they don't "flatten out". Horizontal asymptote is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know what "flattens out" means (and your image doesn't load), but maybe you're thinking of functions of a variable $x$ which tend monotonically to a limit as $x$ tends to infinity. Having a "horizontal asymptote" is another common related term.

Comment: The function is also concave, perhaps even log-concave.

Comment: The image problem might be fixed. And that sounds about right.